# How to prevent commiting file in repository in Git

Tags: git, netbeans, bitbucket

I have a repo with my CMS system I am working on every day. There is a lot of project-specific files (css, js, setup and much more) and I change them in every different project. So i dont want them to be commited when changed, because I need a fresh start everytime. But I need those files to exist (even blank) so I cant just ignore them.

So I assume I can setup --assume-unchanged or --skip-worktree.

But I think its only in my local copy? So next time I will clone the original repo againg I need to set it up again? Its a lot of files so I dont want to waste my time setting it every time.

So: Can I setup my files to never (even on brand new clone) be commited again, but still exist in git repo so I can download whole system at once? Thx

Comment: I think use different project-specific files(not with the same name) for different project is much better.

Answer (score 0):

`--assume-unchanged` will work, but note that every time someone touches the file and commits it, it will reset your bit.

See [Who touched my git assume-unchanged bit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7399153/who-touched-my-git-assume-unchanged-bit) for more info.

Comment: Thx, And would it work also for a new clone of original repo? Because I guess i set it up only in cloned branch so it works only locally?