# Is it impossible to stop tracking a directory in git and remove it locally ensuring it will remaing after a git pull from another machine?

Tags: git, gitignore

I have a directory I no longer want to track. And I even want to remove some files within that directory, without afecting the git. Means I would like to remove the files and don't have git status to show those changes to be commited, so as to avoid a git pull from another machine would end up removing the files.

I already tried the option:

```
git rm --cached directory/
```

but that ended up deleting the files after I did a git pull from another machine.

Also tried:

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged directory/
```

But after deleting the directory I still get an output at git status stating the directory was deleted. I have even added that directory to the .gitignore file.

Is it really impossible to perform such, as stated in the answer under [Stop tracking a file in git - without having it deleted either locally or on pull](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25123374/stop-tracking-a-file-in-git-without-having-it-deleted-either-locally-or-on-pul) ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/600189/2303202

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is "it's not possible".

The problem is not restricted to (and in fact has nothing to do with) directories.  It comes about because the *files* within that directory *really are deleted*.  (It's worth noting here as well that Git does not track *directories* at all, it just creates them when they are needed to contain files.)

Let's pick an actual file name, for completeness.  Call it `conf/config.ini`.  You clone some repository, and it has a file named `conf/config.ini` in it, in commit `badc0ff`, which is the tip commit of branch `master`.  Your Git checks out this commit, so your Git dutifully creates, in your work-tree, a directory `conf` and a file named `config.ini` in that directory.

Now you command your Git to go fetch (`git fetch`) more revisions.  There is one new revision after `badc0ff`, namely `123face`.  Your `origin/master` now names commit `123face`.

Next, you command your Git to integrate the changes from `badc0ff` to `123face` (using `git merge origin/master` or similar).  What are the changes?  Well, along with anything else, someone *removed* `conf/config.ini`.  So your Git removes `conf/config.ini`.

(Note: you may be executing these two Git commands by running `git pull`.  All `git pull` does in this case is run `git fetch` and then `git merge`, so you really *are* using these two other commands.  It's the merge step—going from `badc0ff` to `123face`, obtaining and obeying the changes directed by the upstream—that removes the file; and it removes the file because the file *really is removed*.  That's what it takes to get from one commit to the next.)

#### What to do about this

What's missing here—and has never been considered an important design feature—is a way to tell Git: "Although you may execute a transition from commit *X* to commit *Y* that removes path *P*, please don't actually remove path *P* from the work-tree—remove it from the index only."

Since this is missing, you need a workaround ... and it's really quite simple.  Just check out the previous commit again and save the file—or, equivalently, extract the file from the previous commit without checking it out:

```
$ git show HEAD@{1}:conf/config.ini > conf/config.ini
```

(the `HEAD@{1}` syntax here is from [gitrevisions](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html) and means "the commit `HEAD` pointed to just before we changed it by obeying the change from the upstream").

(If there are many such files, as in your case, it's probably more convenient to `git checkout` the previous commit, i.e., tell your Git to "go back in time" one step, then rename the entire directory-full-of-files out of the way and go back forward in time to the present.  Then you can rename the directory back.)

#### What if your copy of the file is different?

Suppose your `conf/config.ini`, at the time you have *your* Git sitting on commit `badc0ff`, is not quite the same as what's actually *in* commit `badc0ff`.  That is, you've modified your configuration.

If you now run `git merge` (as `git pull` does) to merge in the changes from `123face`, *your Git tells you no:* it cannot do this.  The reason is that your work-tree is not "clean"; you have changes to a tracked, committed file that you have not committed yourself.  Your Git would have to delete the file, which would lose your changes.  So this situation is not supposed to happen in the first place.  To make the merge go, you should commit your changes.  Let's say that you do and you get commit `fedbeef` as a result.

Once you *do* commit your changes, you will be able to merge.  You will get a "merge conflict" on merging their "remove the file" with your "I changed the file", and you can resolve that merge conflict by removing the file.  This gets you the right final state (the file is gone, but if you create it, it will be untracked).  Then you simply extract your committed version from your commit:

```
git show fedbeef:conf/config.ini > conf/config.ini
```

and all is good.

Comment: I may have found a solution. It seems that when I performed "git update-index --no-assume-unchanged directory/" I got "Ignoring path directory/" but that didn´t change anything. If instead I perform "git update-index --no-assume-unchanged directory/*" and in every single file within that directory I can then delete the whole directory and still get everything is up-to-date once I perform a git status.

Comment: The bits you are setting and clearing are indeed per file, or more precisely, per "index entry". But they do not affect whether the file is in, or not in, any given commit; nor do they affect whether the file is to be removed when going from a commit that *has* the file, to a commit that *does not have* the file. Instead, they affect what Git does when it goes to *compare* the file's index entry to the file's state in the work-tree. There are two such bits, and [continued]

Comment: ... the two bits have different purposes: "assume unchanged" tells Git that `stat()` calls are too slow and it should assume the work-tree file matches the index file, while "skip worktree" tells Git that it *must* not compare the work-tree information to the index information. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13630849/git-difference-between-assume-unchanged-and-skip-worktree for details.