# Ignore changes to a tracked file without making it impossible to `git add` the file

Tags: git, git-index

*You may like to skip the preamble.*

---

I have an npm package with the following structure:

```
lib/index.js
src/index.coffee
```

The source file is a CoffeeScript file. I have a make target for building the JavaScript file from the source file. Until recently I included changes to the JavaScript file in each commit, but I now use [xyz](https://github.com/davidchambers/xyz) with a prepublish script:

```
XYZ = node_modules/.bin/xyz --script scripts/prepublish

.PHONY: release-major release-minor release-patch
release-major: LEVEL = major
release-minor: LEVEL = minor
release-patch: LEVEL = patch

release-major release-minor release-patch
    @$(XYZ) --increment $(LEVEL)
```

The prepublish script is straightforward:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -e

rm -f   lib/index.js
make    lib/index.js
git add lib/index.js
```

This means every time I publish a new release (by running `make release-patch`, for example), **lib/index.js** will be rebuilt and added to the release commit. Everything works fine until this point.

---

Since the release script automatically updates the compiled file, I no longer want to update it manually each time I commit. The problem is that after running `make test`, `git status` lists **lib/index.js** as a modified tracked file. I'd like to avoid accidentally committing this file, so I want to prevent it from being listed by `git status`.

The first thing I tried was adding `/lib/` to **.gitignore**. This doesn't work, though, since **lib/index.js** is already being tracked.

I then discovered `git update-index --assume-unchanged`. I ran this command with `lib/index.js` as an argument, and the file is no longer listed by `git status`. So far, so good. Now though, `git add lib/index.js` no longer works, so the prepublish script will fail to do its job.

I believe the prepublish script could run `git update-index --no-assume-unchanged lib/index.js` before `git add`, and could then revert the bit with `git update-index --assume-unchanged lib/index.js`. Is this really the best approach?

To summarize, how does one ignore changes to a tracked file while retaining the ability to `git add` the file?

Answer (score 3):

Check simply if a `git add -f` (`git add --force`) would be able to add the file without the need to unset the `assume-unchanged` bit.

If that doesn't work, then:

> I believe the prepublish script could run `git update-index --no-assume-unchanged lib/index.js` before `git add`, and could then revert the bit with `git update-index --assume-unchanged lib/index.js`.

With this approach, it is the best you can do.

The only other approach is `git update-index --(no-)skip-worktree lib/index.js` (that [I present here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9816844/6309)), but in your case, that would be the same.

Comment: Thanks, @VonC. `git add -f lib/index.js` has no effect, unfortunately. If and when I run into problems with `assume-unchanged` I'll see whether `skip-worktree` is a better option. I'm unclear as to how these two approaches differ (even having read the responses to the [relevant question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6138076/312785)).